# query execution issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query like

```
select user_id ,'abc' as  user_name from t_user where user_refId=123
```

,i want to add one more clause here like

```
select user_id ,
'abc' as  user_name
select count(user) from users as user_num
 from t_user where user_refId=123
```

this is not working out.

Comment: In what way is it "not working out"?  We aren't telepathic.  Please give us some details: describe the observed behaviour including any error messages.  Help us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
select user_id,
      'abc' as user_name, 
       (select count(user) from users)  as user_num
from t_user 
where user_refId=123
```

Answer (score 0):

Please separate `'abc' as  user_name` and `select count(user) from users as user_num` statements by `","` and put second statement in brackets like `(select count(user) from users) as user_num`.

```
      select user_id,
      'abc' as user_name, 
       (select count(user) from users)  as user_num
       from t_user where user_refId=123;
```

Comment: i have al these ,still getting ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause: